# React search filter together with other select filters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want that my search filter work together with my other two select filters.
It means that the search filter should work alone as well as on the filters applied.

When I am applying the search filter to the original items array, the search filter is not working together with the other two filters.

And when I am applying the search filter to filtered items array which results from the other two filters, it is working on them, but when clearing the search field, it is not returning nonfiltered items.

Here is my code snippet:

```
  // Applying filters
  useEffect(() => {
    let result = products.filter((product) => {
      if (
        filter1 !== "" &&
        filter2 !== "" &&
        product.category.toLowerCase() === filter1.toLowerCase() &&
        Math.floor(product.rating.rate) >= filter2
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      if (
        filter1 !== "" &&
        filter2 === "" &&
        product.category.toLowerCase() === filter1.toLowerCase()
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      if (
        filter2 !== "" &&
        filter1 === "" &&
        Math.floor(product.rating.rate) >= filter2
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    setFilteredProducts(result);
  }, [filter1, filter2, products]);
```

```
  // Filtering through Search
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(searchValue);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      let filter = filteredProducts.filter((product) => {
        return (
          Object.values(product)
            .join("")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
        );
      });
      setFilteredProducts(filter);
    }, 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [searchValue, filteredProducts]);
```

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74555269/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the posted "Search" `useEffect` is both setting and listening to the value of `filteredProducts` which might have caused the error.

Since the current code uses 2 `useEffect` for searching and filtering, I think another state `searchedProducts` can be added to store the result of search.

This should allow the searching and filtering to function without contradicting one another, and it just need some minor changes to the existing code.

Here is an example that can be tried:

```
  // Add a state to store result of search
  const [searchedProducts, setSearchedProducts] = useState(products);

  // Filtering through Search
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(searchValue);
    if (!searchValue) {
      setSearchedProducts(products);
      return;
    }
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      const searched = products.filter((product) => {
        return Object.values(product)
          .join("")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
      });
      setSearchedProducts(searched);
    }, 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [searchValue, products]);

  // Applying filters
  useEffect(() => {
    const result = searchedProducts.filter((product) => {
      if (
        filter1 !== "" &&
        filter2 !== "" &&
        product.category.toLowerCase() === filter1.toLowerCase() &&
        Math.floor(product.rating.rate) >= filter2
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      if (
        filter1 !== "" &&
        filter2 === "" &&
        product.category.toLowerCase() === filter1.toLowerCase()
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      if (
        filter2 !== "" &&
        filter1 === "" &&
        Math.floor(product.rating.rate) >= filter2
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    setFilteredProducts(result);
  }, [filter1, filter2, searchedProducts]);
```

Hope this will hope.

Comment: Re *"Hope this will hope."*: That isn't what the second H is for.